# Can I build an app that works with TFS2008 as well as TFS2010? How?

Tags: .net

I am compiling some code that interacts with TFS2008, and I'd like to update it to support TFS2010 as well.

I tried compiling the existing code against the TFS 2010 assemblies (installed with Team Explorer 2010, available on my machine in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies`), and got a compile-time warning:

> warning CS0618: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServer' is obsolete: 'The TeamFoundationServer class is obsolete. Use the TfsTeamProjectCollection or TfsConfigurationServer classes to talk to a 2010 Team Foundation Server.

That brings up the question - will it be possible to have a single code base that communicates with TFS2008 as well as TFS2010?

If I "upgrade" to use TfsTeamProjectCollection (etc) in order to be able to connect with TFS 2010, will the updated code be able to connect with TFS 2008?

Is it a better idea for me to fork the code, and maintain two sets, one to connect to TFS 2008, and one to connect to TFS 2010?

Looking for some insight.

Answer (score 0):

The TFS 2010 API will work for both 2008 and 2010 TFS servers.