# Can I install Team Explorer 2008 as well as Team Explorer 2010 on the same machine?

Tags: .net

> Related:
>   [Can I build an app that works with TFS2008 as well as TFS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206764/can-i-build-an-app-that-works-with-tfs2008-as-well-as-tfs2010-how)

---

Can I install TE2008 on the same machine that runs TE2010?  I'd like to have both the 9.0 and 10.0 versions of the TFS client assemblies available on the machine.

(Apparently when developing applications that connect to TFS, the best way to get the requisite assemblies is to install Team Explorer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. I have them both installed and it works without any problem (on VS2008 and VS2010 respectively).

Comment: +1: Exactly, in the past I've had 2005, 2008 & 2010 on the same machine.